# What is the proper way to get the last entry for each foreign key of a history table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I always wondered what the proper way would be to find the last entry in a history table of a certain foreign key?

Example:

We assume we have a table like this:

**tHistory (ID | FK_User | State | Timestamp)**

What would be the proper way in Oracle to read the lates entry for each FK_User ID? I always used a subselect for this, but it doesn't look right to me... any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative could be to use a correlated sub-query to determine the last date...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tHistory
WHERE
  timestamp = (
    SELECT
      MAX(timestamp)
    FROM
      tHistory latest
    WHERE
      FK_User = tHistory.FK_User
  )
```

Comment: With sensible indexing ( {fk_user,timestamp} in this case), this is actually both fast and readable.

Comment: This might result in multiple rows for a user if that user has two or more timestamps that are the same. Depending on how the results are to be used, this might cause problems.

Comment: @honeyp0t - Absolutely correct.  It's just one way with it's own considerations.  With timestamp data it's less likely as it's almost a continuous value, but you are right; depending on the behaviour of the data the "last time" can relate to multiple records.  The question then becomes "if that's the case, should one or all records be returned, for that timestamp?"

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  h.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY h.FK_User ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rn
        FROM    tHistory h
        )
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: @nino: yes I did. Are you sure you are not confusing a subselect (`scalar = (SELECT …)`) with inline view (`SELECT FROM (SELECT …)`)?

Comment: Agree with Quassnoi on the terminology, a pit fall of jargon (and why I try to use more english words, rather than fewer technical words)

Comment: If it is possible for the timestamp to be null, then I would suggest  DESC NULLS LAST

Comment: @EvilTeach: Wouldn't that be the default?

Comment: I believe you will find, that DESC will put NULLs first by default.  In an ASC sort, they appear last.   Try it and let me know what you find.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

Before version 8i, you would need to use a subquery, for which you need to access the thistory table two times.
When analytic functions were introduced, you could skip the second table access by using the ROW_NUMBER analytic function inside an inline view, like Quassnoi has showed you.

However, since version 9 there is an even better and more performant way in Oracle.
Just group by the FK_USER and use the aggregate functions FIRST or LAST.

FIRST: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions45a.htm#SQLRF00641
LAST: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions57a.htm#83735

Here is an example with a table thistory:

```
SQL> create table thistory (id,fk_user,state,timestamp)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'Me', 'D', sysdate from dual union all
  4  select 2, 'Me', 'C', sysdate-1 from dual union all
  5  select 3, 'Me', 'B', sysdate-2 from dual union all
  6  select 4, 'Me', 'A', sysdate-3 from dual union all
  7  select 5, 'You', 'B', sysdate-11 from dual union all
  8  select 6, 'You', 'A', sysdate-12 from dual
  9  /

Table created.

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'thistory')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> alter session set statistics_level = all
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> set serveroutput off
```

First the pre-8i variant with the subquery:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from thistory
  3   where timestamp =
  4         ( select max(timestamp)
  5             from thistory latest
  6            where fk_user = thistory.fk_user
  7         )
  8  /

        ID FK_USER S TIMESTAMP
---------- ------- - -------------------
         1 Me      D 19-05-2011 11:20:48
         5 You     B 08-05-2011 11:20:48

2 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'allstats last'))
  2  /

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  306v8p42zdz34, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select *   from thistory  where timestamp =        ( select max(timestamp)            from thistory latest
       where fk_user = thistory.fk_user        )

Plan hash value: 2894184026

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name     | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN           |          |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |  1155K|  1155K|  478K (0)|
|   2 |   VIEW               | VW_SQ_1  |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY     |          |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| THISTORY |      1 |      6 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | THISTORY |      1 |      6 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("TIMESTAMP"="VW_COL_1" AND "FK_USER"="THISTORY"."FK_USER")


22 rows selected.
```

Now the analytic function variant:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from ( select h.*
  3                , row_number() over (partition by h.fk_user order by timestamp desc) as rn
  4             from thistory h
  5         )
  6   where rn = 1
  7  /

        ID FK_USER S TIMESTAMP                   RN
---------- ------- - ------------------- ----------
         1 Me      D 19-05-2011 11:20:48          1
         5 You     B 08-05-2011 11:20:48          1

2 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'allstats last'))
  2  /

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  b7zscht24wa2s, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select *   from ( select h.*               , row_number() over (partition by h.fk_user order by timestamp desc)
as rn            from thistory h        )  where rn = 1

Plan hash value: 2357375523

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name     | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |          |      1 |      6 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|          |      1 |      6 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |  9216 |  9216 | 8192  (0)|
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | THISTORY |      1 |      6 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("RN"=1)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY "H"."FK_USER" ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TIMESTAMP") DESC )<=1)


21 rows selected.
```

And finally the most efficient variant using aggregate functions:

```
SQL> select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by timestamp) id
  2       , fk_user
  3       , max(state) keep (dense_rank last order by timestamp) state
  4       , max(timestamp)
  5    from thistory
  6   group by fk_user
  7  /

        ID FK_USER S MAX(TIMESTAMP)
---------- ------- - -------------------
         1 Me      D 19-05-2011 11:20:48
         5 You     B 08-05-2011 11:20:48

2 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'allstats last'))
  2  /

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  9gcbnuf776q27, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by timestamp) id      , fk_user      , max(state) keep
(dense_rank last order by timestamp) state      , max(timestamp)   from thistory  group by fk_user

Plan hash value: 76026975

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY     |          |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |  9216 |  9216 | 8192  (0)|
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| THISTORY |      1 |      6 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


14 rows selected.
```

If you watch the plans carefully, you'll see that the last one is the most efficient.
And it doesn't require an inline view.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Rob.